# Mobile fixed image background css, image scrolling

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm making a website for my girlfriends 23rd birthday and she'll mainly be viewing on mobile. The background image is fixed (no issue on desktop) but on mobile, the image scrolls slightly on the bottom, but adjusts itself after scroll. (Video Attached: https://youtu.be/wKnxYXEy0mg)

CSS Below:

```
body {
   background-image:url(Gold2.jpg);
   display: block;
   background-color: gold;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-position: center;
   min-height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Current address is https://playspace.neocities.org

Answer (score 1):

That's not the background moving, it's Chrome's address bar disappearing.
This behavior is normal, try the website on a different browser.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just downloaded Brave web browser for and Android and I'm having the same issue. You're right, it's because of the address bar, but how do I fix it?

Comment: You don't have to fix nothing. It's the chrome app normal behavior. It's not a problem :)

Comment: You can try to open the website on a small window on pc and you will see that, when you scroll the page down, the background will not moves.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to force off this behavior by using jQuery? jQuery makes it tremendously easy to add and remove classes as well as adding css to them. You could create an if-statement that manually adds the css rule of this background to the section. Another option I'd consider is to add new classes for everything you need in this case scenario and giving everything a z-index above 1 (just to be sure everything is displayed in the chrome browsers mobile app properly). That are just guesses I would realize in your situation although I didn't know this behavior to this point. Hopefully I helped you with your problem... :^)